# Java - how to let jframe to resize to only something smaller than set size

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know how to set the resizing off in jFrame which is

```
setResizable(false);
```

but what I'd to do is to prevent user from making the frame size larger than specific width and height. ( resizing to smaller window size is fine)
How can i do that?

edit:
just tried this, donst do it:

```
  setSize(700,700);
  setVisible(true);
  setLocation(200,200);
  setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
```

Comment: May I ask `why` you would do this? This seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: sure. Suppose that I am displaying a video of size 320X240 inside a jFrame and if i maximize the frame the video has to maximize which makes it very ugly for that low resolution video. Si I don't want user being able to enlarge the jFarem.

Comment: Then keep the video player component/portion of your JFrame at 320x240 and just fill the extra space with "empty" space. A proper layout will take care of this for you with little to no effort. This is the same effect that most any media player on a PC/tablet/smartphone does.

Comment: :) Thanks but for some reason I would like to do it the way i described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

or

```
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

Because of a known [Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6464548) in Swing use this to set the MaxSize:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        Dimension m = getMaximumSize();
        boolean resize = d.width > m.width || d.height > m.height;
        d.width = Math.min(m.width, d.width);
        d.height = Math.min(m.height, d.height);
        
        if (resize) {
            Point p = getLocation();
            setVisible(false);
            setSize(d);
            setLocation(p);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        super.paint(g);
    }
```

Override the paint-method of your JFrame.

Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thanks but for some reason does not do it. please refer to my edited question

Comment: Thats a known Bug in swing: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6464548, but i had this problem as well some time ago, im not totaly sure how i solved it but i think i override an method which handled the resizing of the jframe

Comment: Thank you, man if this is the only way to get around that bug, i will do it.

Comment: the setMaximumSize is made for the layout managers, because of that its not working with jframes. I think its easiest way to get around the bug, and if it works, its allright ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ComponentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and override its [`componentResized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29) method. Although not a perfect solution . But this could let you to achieve what you are looking for. 
But the GUI would keep jerking... I wonder if there is some other better solution for this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MainClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350,250));
        frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt)
            {
                Dimension size = frame.getSize();
                Dimension max = frame.getMaximumSize();
                if (size.getWidth() > max.getWidth())
                {
                    frame.setSize((int)max.getWidth() ,(int) size.getHeight());
                }
                if (size.getHeight() > max.getHeight())
                {
                    frame.setSize((int)size.getWidth() ,(int) max.getHeight());
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(200,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) and add the logic for your desired constraints in [ComponentListener.componentResized()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement component listener to check if the frame has been resized outside the specified bounds:

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (getSize().width > 400 || getSize().height > 400){
                setVisible(false);
                setSize(400, 400);
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Get in your action listener method, then put

```
 xMax=700; yMax=700;

 if((xDim>=xMax)&&(xDim>=xMax))
 {
     setSize(xMax,yMax);
 }
 else
 {
     if(xDim>=xMax)
     {
         setSize(xMax,yDim);
     }
     if(yDim>=yMax)
     {
         setSize(xDim,yMax);
     }
 }
```